# Creating a new user from postman in Strapi v4

Tags: strapi

I need to create a new user using postman

I use the address: http://localhost:1337/api/users, make a POST request to it with the following data:

{

```
"data": {

    "username": "Rafael",

    "email": "rafael@rafael.com",

    "password": "1234",

    "confirmed": false,

    "blocked": false

}
```

}

But I get

{

```
"data": null,

"error": {

    "status": 500,

    "name": "InternalServerError",

    "message": "Internal Server Error"

}
```

}

And in VS Code I get: error: Forbidden access

What could it be?

Comment: You should have more meaningful error messages in your console where you ran the  `develop` command, which might be helpful to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forbidden access 403, can be caused by several things:

1. You didn't pass API token (jwt) to the request header (Bearer token)
2. You have to allow the user/admin role to access User collection.

You can find all the config in the Admin Panel Settings menu.

> Create and manage API token in Strapi: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/optional/api-tokens.html#api-tokens

> Configure admin role access: https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/latest/users-roles-permissions/configuring-administrator-roles.html

> Configure end-user role access: https://docs.strapi.io/user-docs/latest/users-roles-permissions/configuring-end-users-roles.html

Hope it helps!